# Herança está deixando a inicialização da minha aplicação SPRING BOOT lenta

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, spring, spring-boot, herança

Estou trabalhando em um sistema automático de envio de SMS, na minha hierarquia de classes tenho um classe abstrata no topo chamada `TaskNFSBusiness` que define as regras para mensagens que não são em tempo real, ela está anotada com @Component como vocês podem ver abaixo:

```
@Component
public abstract class TaskNFSBusiness {
```

Logo depois tenho uma classe que herda desta classe e define as regras de mensagens que serão enviadas em tempo real sua declaração está sendo feita da seguinte forma:

```
public abstract class NFSInstantanea extends TaskNFSBusiness implements PageQueryConstants {
```

logo mais abaixo na hierarquia tenho 2 classes que herdam de `NFSInstantanea` e definem as regras das mensagens instantâneas, elas estão declaradas da seguinte maneira:

```
@Component
@Qualifier("nfs13")
public class NFS13 extends NFSInstantanea {

@Component
@Qualifier("nfs12")
public class NFS12 extends NFSInstantanea  {
```

O meu problema é que essas duas últimas classes estão aumentando demais o tempo de inicialização do Spring porque ambas herdam de `NFSInstantanea` e ambas estão anotadas com `@Component`, isso está gerando um timeout na hora de subir a aplicação pro servidor de testes local. O mais estranho é que se eu retiro o `@Component` das classes ou se eu faço elas herdarem de `TaskNFSBusiness` o tempo de inicialização volta ao normal, só que eu não queria fazer isso porque aí eu não conseguiria instânciar a `NFS12` e a `NFS13` com `@Autowired`, e se eu botar os métodos de tempo real na `TaskNFSBusiness` eu acabarei tendo uma série de código inútil nas mensagens que não são instantâneas, além de todos os conflitos que isso ocasionaria.

---

Para ficar mais simples de entender a hierarquia vou deixar a modelagem logo abaixo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar que um componente seja inicializado durante a inicialização (ficou esquisito escrever isso), você pode utilizar a anotação `@Lazy` da seguinte forma:

```
@Lazy
@Component
@Qualifier("nfs13")
public class NFS13 extends NFSInstantanea {
...
}
```

Para funcionar, você deve injetá-lo utilizando obrigatoriamente `@Autowired` da seguinte forma:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("nfs13")
private NFSInstantanea minhaInstancia;
```

Ou declarando como um `@Bean`:

```
@Lazy
@Bean
public NFSInstantanea nfs13() {
    return new NFS13();
}
```

Mais informações na [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html)

---

Edit:

Esqueci de mencionar, problemas durante a inicialização da aplicação podem estar relacionadas a rotinas mal otimizadas, que são executadas durante a criação da instância.

É altamente recomendado otimizar as rotinas, ao invés de "utilizar um contorno técnico" para fazer a aplicação funcionar.

Comment: eu consegui fazer a performance voltar anotando a classe `NFSInstantanea` com `@Component`. por algum motivo no Spring(que eu não sei dizer qual) ao anotar a classe pai com `@Component` os filhos também precisam ser anotados(mesmo que essa classe não injete nada dentro dela, como no caso da `NFSInstantanea`) e aí a performance da inicialização fica estável. só que sinceramente isso ficou me cheirando a gambiarra, vou testar este seu método e se ele funcionar mante-lo na minha implementação e vou marcar a pergunta como respondida, obrigado.

Comment: realizei os testes e o seu método realmente funciona @nullptr